# XV6 - usys.s what does this code it do?

Tags: xv6

I have never seen this assembly syntax.

```
#include "syscall.h"
#include "traps.h"
#define SYSCALL(name) \
  .globl name; \
  name: \
    movl $SYS_ ## name, %eax; \
    int $T_SYSCALL; \
    ret

SYSCALL(fork)
SYSCALL(exit)
SYSCALL(wait)
SYSCALL(pipe)
SYSCALL(read)
SYSCALL(write)
SYSCALL(close)
SYSCALL(kill)
SYSCALL(exec)
SYSCALL(open)
SYSCALL(mknod)
SYSCALL(unlink)
SYSCALL(fstat)
SYSCALL(link)
SYSCALL(mkdir)
SYSCALL(chdir)
SYSCALL(dup)
SYSCALL(getpid)
SYSCALL(sbrk)
SYSCALL(sleep)
SYSCALL(uptime)
```

Answer (score 13):

For assembly language file with extension `.S`, `gcc` will use a C preprocessor.

In C, `\` at the end of line means that "connect the next line to this line".
For that reason, the macro becomes

```
#define SYSCALL(name) .globl name; name: movl $SYS_ ## name, %eax; int $T_SYSCALL; ret
```

`##` operator will concatenate the tokens in its left and right.

Therefore, for example, `SYSCALL(fork)` will be expanded to

```
.globl fork; fork: movl $SYS_fork, %eax; int $T_SYSCALL; ret
```

This means

1. make the identifire `fork` public
2. define a label `fork` (this will work as a function)
3. in this function

   1. assign an immediate value `SYS_fork` to register `%eax`
   2. generate an interrupt with code `T_SYSCALL`
   3. return from this function